# Double Click on ListBoxItem with grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, double-click

I have `ListBox` with Grouping and Sorting

```
<Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ListBox x:Name="contactsList" Grid.Row="1"    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" >
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="contactsList_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0,0,5,17"/>
                <StackPanel Height="Auto" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Medium" Height="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusDesc}" Height="Auto" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF3C3C3C"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Result of this is `ListBox` which looks like:

```
+ away
 - contact one
 - contact two
+ unavailable
 - contact three
 - contact four
 - contact five
```

I can expand and collapse this groups.

Next, by double mouse click, I am opening new window and activating it

```
private void contactsList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (contactsList.SelectedValue != null)
    {
           //open new window code   
    }
}
```

But after event is end I am losing focus on opened window, and getting focus on window with `ListBox`.

I was trying to do this by attaching event "`MouseDoubleClick`" on `ListBox`, but it was also invoked by clicking on Header.

For example:
I am choosing "contact one" (one click, not double) then I want to collapse and expand group unavailable. Select on "contact one" remains, and event fire with contact one properties..

Maybe there is option to handle click on header? If so, I could deselect `ListBox`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to catch MouseDoubleClick on ListBox without catching group header clicking (away for ex.)